# I need to gen several bools simultaneously

Tags: specman

I have:

```
struct MyStruct {
     !Ipv4En : bool;
     !Ipv6En : bool;
     keep Ipv4En == TRUE or Ipv6En == TRUE;

     MyMethod() is {
         gen Ipv4En;
         gen Ipv6En;
     };
 };
```

I always get Ipv4En TRUE, because those 2 bools are not generated together.
They can't be generated when I gen MyStruct.
How can I generate them together?

Meanwhile I patched it (don't like the solution): 
I've deleted ! in the definition.

```
temp : MyStruct;
gen temp;

Ipv4En = temp.Ipv4En;
Ipv6En = temp.Ipv6En;
```

Comment: I called `MyMethod()` 100 times and I got cases where `Ipv6En` was `FALSE`. Could you explain in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: Ipv6En can be FALSE because it is generated after Ipv4En. I want to at least one of those bool will be TRUE (I can have both of the TRUE). I want that sometimes Ipv4En will be FALSE and Ipv6En will be TRUE

Comment: I think I spotted the difference. I created one object and called the method on it. You probably create multiple objects. The initial value of both fields is `FALSE` and randomizing only `Ipv4En` forces the solver to choose `TRUE` for it.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the API and replace the two fields with something else?

Comment: The problem is that Ipv4En is always TRUE (because when I gen it for the 1st time, both bools are FALSE. I can try to change the API. I am open to any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a `gen` action only takes a single `gen-item`, you have to group the two variables you want solved together. You can do this by defining a new `struct`:

```
struct IpVersionInfo {
  Ipv4En: bool;
  Ipv6En: bool;

  keep Ipv4En == TRUE or Ipv6En == TRUE;
};
```

Instead of having two variables for your enables, you use a single variable of this new `struct` type:

```
struct MyStruct {
    !ipVersionInfo: IpVersionInfo;

    MyMethod() is {
        gen ipVersionInfo;
    };
};
```

If you run a couple of iterations, you'll see that you can reach all combinations:

```
extend sys {

    run() is also {
        for i from 1 to 20 {
            var s: MyStruct = new;
            s.MyMethod();
            outf(
                    "Ipv4En = %s, Ipv6En = %s\n",
                    s.ipVersionInfo.Ipv4En,
                    s.ipVersionInfo.Ipv6En);
        };
    };

};
```

This requires an API change, though, so you'll need to update all code that referenced `Ipv4En` and `Ipv6En`.

Aside from grouping the two fields in a `struct`, there are also other ways of solving your problem. Another example would be to define an `enum` that contains values for your legal cases:

```
type ip_version_info_e: [ V4, V6, BOTH ];
```

As before, you can use a variable of this type in your `struct`:

```
struct MyStruct {
    !ip_version_info: ip_version_info_e;

    MyMethod() is {
        gen ip_version_info;
    };
};
```

If you run a couple of iterations of the new code you'll see that it also reaches all possible combinations:

```
extend sys {

    run() is also {
        for i from 1 to 20 {
            var s: MyStruct = new;
            s.MyMethod();
            outf(
                    "Ipv4En = %s, Ipv6En = %s\n",
                    s.ip_version_info in [ V4, BOTH ],
                    s.ip_version_info in [ V6, BOTH ]);
        };
    };

};
```

Regardless of how you decide to solve the problem, you should hide the internal implementation from any client code that uses `MyStruct`. Notice that the `out` statements from above look different depending on how we chose to handle the IP version settings. Instead of having client code look too deep inside `MyStruct` you should define the following two methods:

```
isIpv4Enabled(): bool;
isIpv6Enabled(): bool;
```

In the case where we grouped the two Boolean variables in a `struct`, the implementations of these two methods are:

```
struct MyStruct {
    // ...

    isIpv4Enabled(): bool is {
        result = ipVersionInfo.Ipv4En;
    };

    isIpv6Enabled(): bool is {
        result = ipVersionInfo.Ipv6En;
    };
};
```

In the case where we defined an `enum`, we have:

```
struct MyStruct {
    // ...

    isIpv4Enabled(): bool is {
        result = ip_version_info in [ V4, BOTH ];
    };

    isIpv6Enabled(): bool is {
        result = ip_version_info in [ V6, BOTH ];
    };
};
```

In both cases, though, the client code for printing would be the same:

```
extend sys {

    run() is also {
        for i from 1 to 20 {
            var s: MyStruct = new;
            s.MyMethod();
            outf(
                    "Ipv4En = %s, Ipv6En = %s\n",
                    s.isIpv4Enabled(),
                    s.isIpv4Enabled());
        };
    };

};
```

This is a major advantage. This way you are free to change your implementation of `MyStruct` in the future and not have to touch any other code that uses it.